# How to use random and the split function together in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This function is supposed to output random characters with commas, but there is no output

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to display a random number.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var random_list = randomizeList([1,2,3,4,49,'foo',38,'bar',9,-1]);
var n=random_list.split(" ");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's `randomizeList`?

Comment: Doesn't split only work on strings? (Assuming the return from `randomizeList()` is an array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list should be a CSV String if you plan on using the `split` function.  After splitting use a randomized number to get the index of the array.

**HTML**

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to display a random number.</p>

<button id="mybutton">Submit</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var button = document.getElementById("mybutton");
button.onclick = function(){myFunction()}
function myFunction()
{
var random_list = "1,2,3,4,59,foo,38,bar,9,-1";
var n=random_list.split(",");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n[Math.floor((Math.random()*n.length))];
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/bGV5y/1/